# Sublime Text2 spell check color variation

Tags: colors, sublimetext2

I'm experiencing that Sublime Text 2 (ST2) changes colors of the words that are marked by the spell checker with a red snakeline underneath them. This behaviour happens as I scroll or type words, and the color switches between pitch black or radioactive green. It doesn't seem to be a pattern in the variations.

Examples:

- Before color behaviour occurs: http://grab.by/hL6y
- The radioactive green color behaviour: http://grab.by/hL6E

Anyone else experiencing this? It's quite freaking annoying. I'm on a 2012 Macbook pro retina with Mountain Lion, using the Solarized Dark colour scheme for ST2 (I've tried multiple, but same behaviour for all), and would love a fix! I've tried the Sublimetext.com forum, but nobody has a fix.

Comment: You put that post up less than a week ago.  Actually, once you posted these images of what is occurring on your system you have already got someone to respond there. Anyway, I occasionally get some of my text flash black for a second. Good luck finding an answer!

Comment: @AGS Yeah, you're right about the sublimetext.com/forum post. Sorry for the inconsistency, I'm in the process of writing my masters degree, and it feels like ages since I got fed up of the color behaviour :P

Answer (score 0):

There may now be a viable workaround -- a spell check alternative.

https://github.com/phyllisstein/CheckBounce

The default syntaxes will need to be defined within the user configuration files.  It now defaults to Markdown, Text, and Tex.

The built-in spell check of ST2 should be turned off when enabling the CheckBounce package.

The dictionary of words added in Mountain Lion is stored in:

`/Users/insert_your_user_name_here/Library/Spelling/LocalDictionary`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same kind of behaviour with the CheckBounce package, thus indicating that it's not a package problem.

Comment: There was an update (i.e., bug fix) to the package posted by the CheckBounce author at about 10:30 p.m. (P.S.T.) on April 5, 2013.  I have not yet experienced any difficulties with the latest release.  I will continue to use it for Tex and Text syntaxes, and report back if I experience any problems with the latest release.  I have updated my post to say "there may now be . . ." instead of "there is . . ."  ST2 built-in spell check would of course need to be turned off, so there is only one spell check program active (i.e., CheckBounce).